# J Pole, what is the best way to deal with Common Mode Current?

Tags: antenna-system, coaxial-cable, feed-line, choke-balun, j-pole

I am planning on utilising a ferrite choke on a J Pole antenna for CMC. Placement directly on the feedpoint poses possible mechanical restraints. Is it okay to place it a quarter wave down the coaxial feed line in free space from the feed point. Is this the maximum point of resistance to the flow of CMC? Or is this a bad idea due to resonant coupling?
Addition:
From reading one of the suggested articles it mentioned measuring from the ends of the antenna and to place a choke at odd multiples of a quarter wavelength... where convenient. So I assume that with a J Pole, this would be measured from the top of this antenna. Have I interpreted this correctly? Anyone, anyone? The article was a little vague and skimmed over a few things. A mere squire like myself struggles to join the dots or 'missing links' if you will.

Comment: Hi Francis! Check out [this Q&A](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/881/1550) which I think directly answers your question.

Comment: Also, https://ham.stackexchange.com/search?q=J-pole+common+

Comment: And https://ham.stackexchange.com/search?q=J-pole+choke