# Does the varactor bias supply have to be independent of Vcc?

Tags: power-supply, varicap

A quick follow-up to [How can I tell the frequency without an oscilloscope, or frequency counter?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/2346/how-can-i-tell-the-frequency-without-an-oscilloscope-or-frequency-counter)

My supply is a transformer plucked from a dead power adapter rated for 1.5A. This is rectified cap-filtered, then Vo manipulated through an LM317 with a pair of 1k linear.

I plan to tap the capacitor output to power the oscillator, and use the 317 output to bias the varactor.

Does the varactor bias supply have to be distinct from Vcc?

Comment: What do you mean by "independent" or "distinct"?

Comment: Just that. E.g. Vvaractor = dedicated battery

Comment: Then the answer is no. The question might be better if you explain why you think a separate battery is necessary, then there would be more to say than "no".

Comment: Let me catch you in the shack ... hang on.

Comment: @VU2NHW So if the discussion has been had, is there an answer to this question now?

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO: Yes. No.

Comment: @PhilFrost: Could you please convert that comment above to an answer I may accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can derive the bias from Vcc just fine. You will want to make sure the bias voltage is well-regulated and low-noise, since any error or noise will be manifest in the tuning of your radio. Nothing that can't be accomplished by a voltage regulator and a bit of filtering, however.